# SQL commit not working

Tags: mysql, commit, rollback

I am trying to use rollback to get back to the previous statement where I commit.But it's not working.It always shows the current statement. Which means commit is not working? How can I solve it?

```
drop table departments_dup;
create table departments_dup
(
 dept_no char(4),
 dept_name varchar(40)
 );

insert into departments_dup
select * from departments;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    departments_dup
ORDER BY dept_no;

commit;

UPDATE departments_dup 
SET 
    dept_name = 'Quality Control',
    dept_no = 'd021';

ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql has autocommit true by default, so you can open transaction before sentences and commit to the end;

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE departments_dup 
  SET 
  dept_name = 'Quality Control',
  dept_no = 'd021';

ROLLBACK;
```

Or you can to set autocommit false, adding the following to the [mysqld] section of your **my.cnf** file.

```
init_connect='set autocommit=0'
```

This would set autocommit to be off for every client though.